# Lightbox using an area map in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

I am trying to use Lightbox with an area map. I have gotten it to work fine with Firefox, but in Internet Explorer, it simply opens a new window. I tried using Slimbox, but it doesn't seem to support area maps at all.

Suggestions? Here is the HTML code:

```
<div align="center"><img src="images/background-temporary.jpg" width="667" height="475" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area href="images/background-temporary.jpg" shape="poly" coords="236,396,267,396,269,428,237,429,236,396"  />

</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, wow. When did I lose the "rel="lightbox"" attribute. I fail.

Comment: Try to edit your old post instead of and answer to your old question

Answer (score 1):

This should work in any browser, not just IE.
In the area maps, add an id tag.

```
    <area shape="rect" id="yourid"  coords="5,65,132,116" alt="Your Alt Description" />
```

Outside the map add this sort of code to the html with an empty span that has an id inside the a tags.

```
    <a href="an_image.jpg" rel="lightbox[a]" Title="My title"><span id="empty_span"></span></a>
```

Using javaScript, do something like this

```
    <script>
    $('area').click(function(){
         $("#empty_span").click();
    });
    </script>
```

For multiple areas you can create multiple click functions or number the ids in both the area tags and the click functions - as follows:

```
    <map etc....
    <area shape="rect" id="id1" coords="5,65,132,116"   alt="1st Description" />
    <area shape="rect" id="id2" coords="55,65,132,116"  alt="2nd Description" />
    <area shape="rect" id="id3" coords="105,65,132,116" alt="3rd Description" />
    </map>

    <a href="1st_image.jpg" rel="lightbox[a]" Title="1st title"><span id="span1"></span></a>
    <a href="2nd_image.jpg" rel="lightbox[a]" Title="2nd title"><span id="span2"></span></a>
    <a href="3rd_image.jpg" rel="lightbox[a]" Title="3rd title"><span id="span3"></span></a>

    <script>
    $('area').click(function(){
          $("#span"+$(this).attr("id").substr(2)).click();
    });
    </script>
```